# Known Results on Convexity of Numerical Range

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-analysis, convex-analysis

Let $A_1,A_2,\dots,A_M$ be given $N\times N$ hermitian matrices. The numerical range is defined as the set
\begin{align}
\mathbb{S}=\{(u^HA_1u,\dots,u^HA_Mu)\in \mathbb{R}^M\mid u^Hu=1\}
\end{align}
By toeplitz hausdorff theorem, $\mathbb{S}$ is convex for

1. $M=2$, $N\geq 2$, no conditions on $A_i$
2. $M=3$, $N\geq 3$, no conditions on $A_i$
3. $A_i$'s are tridiagonal and real in some basis. No conditions on $M$ and $N$. (from Nathaniel Johnston's answer).

I would like to know the other cases where $\mathbb{S}$ is convex. Can some body point me to known references?

Comment: Can you be more clear about what you mean by "other cases"? If you are only allowed to consider $M$ and $N$, then the conditions you listed are optimal (i.e., the numerical range can be non-convex for all other choices of $M,N$). So do you want conditions on the $A_i$'s instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only result of this nature that I'm aware of (beyond the two cases involving $M$ and $N$ that you've listed) is Theorem 3.1 in "C.-K. Li and Y.-T. Poon. [Convexity of the joint numerical range](http://people.wm.edu/~cklixx/poon-1.pdf). SIAM J. Matrix Analysis Appl. 21 (1999), 668-678", which basically says that the numerical range is convex when each of the $A_i$'s are tridiagonal and real in some basis.